# How can I change the keys to change desktop in windows 10 with autohotkey?

Tags: windows, autohotkey

Windows 10 has finally multi desktops, you can switch desktops with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>win</kbd>+<kbd>right</kbd> (or <kbd>left</kbd>) keys. It's a nice feature, but you have two use two hands to switch desktops.
I'm trying to map the keys like this with autohotkey so I can use just one hand and keep the other one in the mouse..

```
ctrl + mouse wheel up   --> ctrl + win + right
ctrl + mouse wheel down --> ctrl + win + left
```

the message box comes up so the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + wheel up is working, but it doesn't switches desktops.

```
~LControl & WheelUp::
MsgBox, Go to desktop right.
Send, {ctrl up}{lwin ctrl righ}
return

~LControl & WheelDown::
MsgBox, Go to desktop left.
Send, {ctrl up}{lwin ctrl left}
return
```

Any idea why is this not working?.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside `{}` only one key should be specified and I think there's no need for passthrough modifier `~`:

```
LCtrl & WheelUp::Send, {LCtrl up}{LWin down}{LCtrl down}{Right}{LWin up}{LCtrl up}
LCtrl & WheelDown::Send, {LCtrl up}{LWin down}{LCtrl down}{Left}{LWin up}{LCtrl up}
```

Maybe [the standard syntax](http://ahkscript.org/docs/Hotkeys.htm) for modifier keys will also work without sending up-event for `LCtrl` key:

```
LCtrl & WheelUp::Send, #{Right}
LCtrl & WheelDown::Send, #{Left}
```

Answer (score 4):

You can easily switch between two virtual desktops in Windows 10 by using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>→</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd> shortcuts.

But to make this even simpler and easy to use I’ve made this Autohotkey script to toggle betweeen two virtual desktops by just using the (`) key which is the least used key in keyboard.

```
`::
if (Toggle := !Toggle)
    Send #^{right}
else
    Send #^{left}
return
```

***Note:-*** This script works for switching between two desktops only. For creating another virtual desktop you can use the shortcut Ctrl+Win+D.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question but there is now a much better solution that has official support from Microsoft and is really easy to use.  Microsoft has recently released an open source tool called Powertoys https://github.com/microsoft/PowerToys . It includes a keyboard manager with a tool for remapping keyboard shortcuts.  Its really simple.

Comment: This does not address the question of using autohotkey nor does PowerToys work for changing desktops.

Comment: At time of the original question Autohotkey was the only option with registery edits.  Now there is a different option with better MS support.  I'm also not sure what you mean when you say PowerToys dosent work for changing desktops.  Under Keyboard manager there is a section called remap shortcuts that allows for the remapping of all windows defualt shourtcuts.

Comment: Thank you. This should be the way to go now.