# Autohotkey Windows 10 Desktop Switch with Empty Desktop

Tags: windows-10, autohotkey

I wrote a similar autohotkey script as [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685314/how-can-i-change-the-keys-to-change-desktop-in-windows-10-with-autohotkey) but am having trouble whenever a windows virtual desktop is empty (no windows open), for some reason the windows keyup doesn't get sent and is stuck down. This behavior does not occur when I input the sequence manually. Any suggestions on how to overcome this?

Here's my script:

```
WheelRight:: Send {LWin Down}{Ctrl Down}{Right}{Ctrl Up}{LWin Up}
```

I've also tried:

```
WheelRight:: #^Right
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

A few restarts later, it looks like the problem is solved. Not sure what caused it originally.