# I want to do the same thing done here with ahk but using right mouse button

Tags: windows, autohotkey

so I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32685314/how-can-i-change-the-keys-to-change-desktop-in-windows-10-with-autohotkey/32688452#32688452) post which was very similar to mine but i want to do the same thing op wanted to do but instead of holding down ctrl i hold down right mouse button. thank you.

I tried something like this:

```
suspend
send {RButton Down}{WheelUp}{RButton Up}::Send, {LControl Down}{LWin Down} 
{Right}{LWin Up}{LControl Up}
return


F12::suspend
```

But this performs the action immediately when I run the script which is not what I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There you go,

```
~RButton & WheelUp::
    Send, {LWin down}{LCtrl down}{Right}{LWin up}{LCtrl up}
    return

~RButton & WheelDown::
    Send, {LWin down}{LCtrl down}{Left}{LWin up}{LCtrl up}
    return
```

just replaced the key combination and add a passthrought so right click works

Comment: If i may ask, what is the ~ used in the beginning for?

Comment: ~ allows the key combination to passthrough after executing the code